# Passing variable through html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

It is possible to pass variables to a jquery event using custom html attribute

```
<input type="text" id="custominput" data-ajax-id="1">

$("#custominput").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).data("ajax-id"));
}
```

I tried using the same method for a spinner, but this isn't working. I would like to set max through a html custom attribute

```
<input type="text" id="spinnercount" class="form-control ui-spinner-input" name="groupcount" value="10" data-ajax-max="10" role="spinbutton">


$("#spinnercount").spinner({
    max: $(this).data("ajax-max")
})
```

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to access attribute `data-ajax-id`

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working" ? `$("#spinnercount").data("ajax-max")` is retrieving the value.

Comment: You can access using [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. `alert($(this).attr("data-ajax-id"));`, also, there's a syntax error on your first example, it's missing a `)`

Comment: @TehSoTo why not use `data` for accessing data?

Comment: I was just pointing out another way of accessing it. Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" is not what you expect it to be.

in your first example you are in the scope of a function. jquery sets the calling element(s) to be "this" there.

in your 2nd code you are in the global scobe.

try:

```
var spinnerCountElement = $("#spinnercount");

spinnerCountElement.spinner({
    max: spinnerCountElement.data("ajax-max")
})
```